# Filtering each X in DataFrame with values from other Series/DataFrame (area under curve)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, pandas-groupby

I'm filtering over a DataFrame to get the area under a curve. I've managed to get the border of the curve, such that we only want rows under that curve.

The way I've gone about this is by getting the `data_y_border` **(red curve in diagram)** with (1) in the code below (this works fine). This will contain the topmost Y for each X where the values of another column are >= 0.7, such that I can query `data_y_border[x_value]` and get the corresponding topmost Y.

Note: `data_y_border` is not the lowest values of Y in the entire dataset. `data` **(blue rectangle in diagram)** is our dataset, and `data_y_border` is the lower boundary of the red area defined by the `Density` column where its values are above 0.7:

```
    density_zone = data[
        (full_dataset["X" < x_right_boundary)
        & (full_dataset['Density'] >= 0.7)
        & (full_dataset['Y'] > y_lower_boundary)
    ]
```

`data_y_border` is the bottom of the red region. Anything under it doesn't have a Density > 0.7.

[image: Area under a curve]

I now want to use the Y value for each X position to keep all rows **where that X value corresponds to a Y <= its topmost Y (in`data_y_border`)**.

I'm trying a combination of `loc` and `lambda` in [2] below to compare the row value to the topmost Y per row but I'm getting errors saying:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Code:

```
[1] data_y_border = density_zone.groupby("X")["Y"].min() #returns Series

                          or

    data_y_border = density_zone.loc[density_zone.groupby("X")["Y"].idxmin() # returns DataFrame
    # as per @enke's suggestion

[2] data.loc[lambda row: row['Y'] <= data_y_border.get(row['X'])]

    # get the X value for `row`, 
    # use it as the index in `data_y_border` to get the corresponding Y // value, 
    # compare that row's Y value to see if it's less than or equal to the topmost Y. 
    # If it is, keep it
```

The DataFrame has about 23 columns in it, but as an example, given the following `data` DataFrame and `data_y_border`, I would expect to keep the expected out below:

```
data = 
X    Y        OtherDataIWantToKeep
2.0  307.0    ...
2.0  155.3    ...     
2.0  120.0    ...     
2.0  80.2     ...        
4.0  500.3    ...
4.0  270.8    ...
4.0  111.2    ...
4.0  78.23    ...
4.0  6.3      ...

data_y_border=
2.0, 155.3
4.0, 111.2
```

expected output rows (including all data from other columns):

```
X    Y        OtherDataIWantToKeep
2.0  155.3    ...     
2.0  120.0    ...     
2.0  80.2     ...        
4.0  111.2    ...
4.0  78.23    ...
4.0  6.3      ...
```

I've tried combinations involving `.apply` instead, but I get key errors with that approach. I get the feeling the issue is with the `data_y_border.get(row['X'])` part of the code above, where Pandas doesn't like running a query on a separate filter in order to use that value to filter the current DataFrame.

Is using `loc` and `lambda` not the right way to filter over every row in a DataFrame to compare each row's value to a mapped out in another DataFrame/Series?

I've considered `iterrows` for this (if it were Arrays/Lists in Python/JS I would have mapped over them) but that feels too expensive for a pretty sizeable DataFrame

Comment: @enke Thanks, I replied to you answer. It's giving me the same output as [1] above which is already working fine in my code. It's [2] that is giving me trouble

Comment: `data_y_border` you have there cannot be the output of `data.groupby("X")["Y"].min()`. For example, `120.0<155.3` for `2.0`. How is `data_y_border` derived actually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment:

> The curve is based on values from another column. It's basically rows
> where values for another column are greater than a certain value, find
> the lowest Y for each X. That becomes our curve boundary. Using that
> curve we want to find the rows in the area beneath the curve.

it seems `data_y_border` is calculated independently from `data`. So let's take it as given (as given in the question). Then we could `map` it to `data['X']` and compare it with `data['Y']`; then filter:

```
out = data[data['Y'] <= data['X'].map(data_y_border.set_index('X')['Y'])]
```

Output:

```
     X       Y OtherDataIWantToKeep
1  2.0  155.30                  ...
2  2.0  120.00                  ...
3  2.0   80.20                  ...
6  4.0  111.20                  ...
7  4.0   78.23                  ...
8  4.0    6.30                  ...
```

Comment: Thanks but both of these provide the same dataset as what we get in [1] above (i.e. the border under the curve) which is already working fine. 

I've updated the question for clarity.

Comment: @GroomedGorilla I don't understand what you mean. If you have the minimum of a curve, then there are no points below it, right?

Comment: The curve is based on values from another column. It's basically rows where values for another column are greater than a certain value, find the lowest Y for each X. That becomes our curve boundary. Using that curve we want to find the rows in the area beneath the curve. I'll add a diagram to explain

Comment: Turns out there was a gap in our data which is why this took longer to validate. It works! `data_y_border` in my code above returns a Series, so `set_index` wouldn't work, but I converted it to a DataFrame (then later swapped it for a cleaner implementation based on your previous answer using `idxmin`). I'll try to update the question title to something clearer too. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Can't you create a `data_y_mins_index and data_y_mins_values` from `data_y_mins` in the same dataframe from `Y and X`?
Then you can filter like:

```
data[data['Y']<=data['y_min_value']]
```

Comment: So you mean filter out the y values as in [1] in my question, then add them as columns to the `data` DataFrame? The problem there would be how populate those columns based on the max allowed Y for each X. Going through the rows in the dataset each X would need to map to the data_y_borders value for that X-coordinate

Comment: You can do that by applying a function to each line that gets this desired value. See more about apply/applymap in dataframes.